# Подключение заголовочных файлов на С

Tags: c

Подскажите, в чем разница между этими двумя способами подключения заголовочного файла в С:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

и

```
#include "stdlib.h"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При использовании угловых скобкок, файл ищется в определенном списке каталогов, который задаётся в настройках компилятора `-I`.

При использовании кавычек, файл ищется в первую очередь в директории самой программы, потом в определённом списке, который задаётся в настройках компилятора `-iquote`.

Не уверен, правильно ли я понял, но в русской литературе не замечал описания двух этих способов.

*Источник: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html*

Comment: Спасибо. Вспомнил, что-то подобное где-то слышал.

Comment: файлы в **кавычках** однозначно **ищутся** в каталогах, которые задаются при вызове компилятора через **-I** .

Comment: @avp, gcc.gnu.org не авторитетный источник?:)

Comment: Причем здесь источник ???  Берем программу t.c:

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "a.h"

    main () {   printf ("%d\n",NNN); }

файл a.h с \#define NNN 100 делаем в ../



    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/tst$ gcc t.c -I ..
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/tst$ ./a.out 
    100
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/tst$ gcc t.c 
    t.c:3:15: фатальная ошибка: a.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
         компиляция прервана.
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/tst$ 

**Вопросы есть ?**

Comment: ../ это же в категории на уровень выше, я правильно понимаю? А речь шла вроде бы о той же самой категории, разве нет? Когда t.c и a.h находятся в одной категории, все прекрасно компилируется.

Comment: Иными словами:
`insolor@andLinux:/mnt/win/test$ ls
a.h  t.c
insolor@andLinux:/mnt/win/test$ gcc t.c
insolor@andLinux:/mnt/win/test$ ls
a.h  a.out  t.c
insolor@andLinux:/mnt/win/test$ ./a.out
100
insolor@andLinux:/mnt/win/test$ `

Comment: Естественно компилируется, собственно именно это я и показал в своем примере. 

Изначально комментарий был о том, **где** ищутся файлы в кавычках, поскольку ответ @Crasher в этой области не полон. Файлы в кавычках  ищутся в текущем каталоге и **всех** каталогах передаваемых через **-I.**

То, что они ищутся в текущем каталоге в комментарии не было указано, т.к. это **абсолютно очевидно.**

Файлы в угловых скобках ищутся в предопределенных каталогах (в первую очередь: /usr/include, для остальных здесь места мало), а также в каталогах передаваемых через -I.

--

Теперь кажется все.

Comment: Ребята, я балдею. Такую элементарнейшую тему обсасываете второй день.

Answer (score 1):

Угловые скобки обозначают, что файл <stdlib.h> будет взят из некоторого стандартного каталога, обычно это /usr/include. 
 Кавычки "" -обозначает символьную строку  Кавычки не являются частью строки. Они вводятся только для того, чтобы отметить ее начало и конец. Препроцессор заменяет эту строку содержимым файла stdlib.h

Comment: Кавычки "" в директиве #include означают не текстовую строку, а то что файл будет искаться в первую очередь в каталоге где лежит данный исходник

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки "" это для Препроцессора, чтобы искал файл в текущем каталоге по этой строке и выкидывать их поэтому нельзя

Comment: Не только в текущем, но и во всех каталогах, указанных с флагом -I при компиляции.  

Т.е. если в файле t.c есть \#include "a.h"  , то  команда gcc t.c -I /tmp -I .. -I ./xaxa будет искать файл с именем a.h в каталогах ./ .. /tmp и ./xaxa